# Windows server python running using pm2 opening cmd.exe multiple instances

Tags: python, pm2

I have the following ecosystem.config.json to run python application in windows server. I see that C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe is opening and closing continously. my code has no reference to open a cmd. Not sure what is missing.

```
# start.sh file
python -m pip install pipenv
python -m pipenv install
python -m pipenv run app.py 

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'dev',
      script: 'start.sh',
      env: {
        ENV: 'dev',
        DB_NAME: 'db-dev',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```